# How to customize youtube url to dynamic pretty url?

Tags: seo, htaccess

I am creating seo friendly links for my site. I am succeeded in creating all link just the data fetch from youtube using Api is creating an ugly and long link i want is there any way out to make that link seo friendly
here it is...

```
 http://example.com/movie_trailer.php?video_url=dqX6OwCHvzQ&video_data=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dqX6OwCHvzQ/mqdefault.jpg&video_title=Loveshhuda%20Official%20Trailer%20-%20Girish%20Kumar,%20Navneet%20Dhillon%20|%20Latest%20Bollywood%20Movie%20|%2019%20Feb%202016
```

if possible please do tell me.....

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via .htaccess file.

This file is used by Apache WebServer to read the configuration and directives, then it applies these directives to directory or subdirectory level (Depends on where you placed your .htaccess file).

and the best part of that file is:

> If there is any error in .htaccess file, you get the internal server
>   misconfiguration error with error code 500.

so you backup your file.

I don't want to write full method how to do it, but I can provide you a link so you can understand it more clearly for the future references. [**Click here for details.**](http://webrewrite.com/url-rewriting-htaccess/)

Comment: The link you provided gave me the knowledge that i already have i need to change you tube url how can i do it.